# Jenkins: Is it possible to create an Ivy job using Jenkinsfile? (pipeline as code)

Tags: jenkins, ivy, jenkins-pipeline

I have several projects that use Ivy and therefore I created Ivy jobs that build and publish my artifacts to a repository.

The Ivy plug-in is pretty useful since it takes care of dependencies for me in an automated fashion. However, I am moving these jobs to a "pipeline as code" approach and want to use `Jenkinsfile`s to automatically create the jobs for each of my projects.

My doubt is: can I create the very same jobs (Ivy) using a `Jenkinsfile`? If not, can I create any sort of Ivy job using a `Jenkinsfile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Job DSL plugin from within a Jenkinsfile to create new jobs, see https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/User-Power-Moves#use-job-dsl-in-pipeline-scripts

The following pipeline code calls the Job DSL build step which will then run the `ivyJob.groovy` Job DSL script.

```
node {
  step([
    $class: 'ExecuteDslScripts',
    scriptLocation: [targets: ['ivyJob.groovy']],
    removedJobAction: 'DELETE',
    removedViewAction: 'DELETE',
    lookupStrategy: 'SEED_JOB',
  ])
}
```

The `ivyJob.groovy` script will then create an Ivy job and run an Ant build:

```
ivyJob('example') {
  ivyBuilder {
    ant {
      target('clean')
      targets(['test', 'publish'])
      buildFile('build.xml')
      antInstallation('Ant 1.9')
      prop('key', 'value')
      javaOpt('-Xmx=1G')
    }
  }
}
```

See the Job DSL API documentation for details:
https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/ivyJob